# кодирование базы данных

Tags: python, база-данных

Cуществует база данных, заполненная текстовыми ответами на некие вопросы:

Пример:

```
один  
лдин  
вдвоем  
втроем  
один  
влвоем  
и т.д
```

Необходимо каждому уникальному значению поставить в соответствие уникальный код (любое число), причем значения "один" и "лдин" считаются одинаковыми.
в конечном итоге необходимо вывести данную базу с числовыми значениями

Пример:

```
один  31  
вдвоем 41  
втроем 59
```

Пробовал реализовать на python, используя `SequenceMatcher` и `fuzzy`, но безуспешно.

Comment: А что такое лдин или длвоем? Добавте ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

1. Первым делом заберите данные из вашей т.н. базы данных, используйте библиотеки для работы с DB (например psycopg2 - для postgresql, csv - если это csv-файл вдруг и т.д.).
2. Примените к полученным данным вашу функции-фильтр, которая будет считать, что "один" это "лдин" и почистит ненужные значения. Например она может выглядеть следующим образом и включать в себя справочник поправок. Вы можете его создать всё в той же базе или конфигурационном файле.

   ```
   def f_replace(x):
       my_dict = {"лдин": "один", "тры": "три"}
       # return [my_dict[a] if a in my_dict else a for a in x]
       t = []
       for m in x:
           if m in my_dict:
               t.append(my_dict[m])
           else:
               t.append(m)
       return t
   ```
3. Полученные данные добавьте в set(), тем самым исключив дублирующиеся элементы.

   ```
   t = ["один", "один", "три", "три"]
   set(t)
   set(['один', 'три'])
   ```
4. Добавьте числовые идентификаторы:

   ```
   t2 = {'один', 'три'}
   t3 = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(t2, range(1, len(t2) + 1))]
   for i, j in t3:
       print i, j
   три 1
   один 2
   ```

*Используйте utf-8, если русские символы.